# In Autosar, how do we decide which SWC/BSW should go to trusted OS Application and which SWC/BSW should go to Non Trusted OS application?

Tags: partitioning, autosar

I am trying to design a Autosar system for Cluster application. In the OS, I can see that there are Trusted OS applications and Non Trusted OS applications. I am not able to understand the difference between these. Also I am unable to decide which SWCs and BSW modules should be made Trusted and which ones to make Non Trusted. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these partitions are there to save you development costs, since it's easier to develop QM components.

You should only place ASIL-D (trusted) SwC-s in the trusted partition and SwCs with less safety shall be allocated to non-trusted.

If a trusted SwC has a Connector to non-trusted component, then it shall be prepared for that interface's input data's Physical or Internal constraints being violated.

Answer (score 1):

From [AUTOSAR_SWS_OS](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/20-11/AUTOSAR_SWS_OS.pdf):

> Trusted: An OS-Application that may be executed in privileged mode and
> may have unrestricted access to the API and hardware
> resources. Only trusted applications can provide trusted
> functions.

> Non-trusted: An OS-Application that is executed in non-privileged mode has
> restricted access to the API and hardware resources.

This gets interesting if you have a mixed criticality application, usually because of different ASILs assigned by functional safety according to ISO26262.
Either you would have to develop the whole AUTOSAR stack and all SWCs according to the highest ASIL, or you would have to ensure the freedom from interference between them.

I am assuming the case that you want to use this freedom from interference way now:

To get there, first you need the functional safety requirements for your software, including their ASIL level.

Then you distribute the implementation of these functional safety requirements across your SWCs, including Runnables.

The ASIL is assigned on SWC level (except another possibility came up recently and I missed that).

Then you split the SWCs with different ASILs in different applications, each having memory and/ or timing protection (to be defined together with your functional safety manager).

If, according to the mapping in your software architecture, the used BSWs also have functional safety responsibility, they also need to be developed according to the respective ASIL. Whether they are, you can learn from the functional safety case provided with your AUTOSAR stack. If there is no-one, your AUTOSAR stack is just for QM and not suited for functional safety applications.

Most of the stuff can theoretically run in non-trusted applications, because there are guarded APIs.
Check your BSW/ MCAL documentation where this is not working.
Also you might need to change this to reduce resource consumption.
Depending on your processor and the chosen protections, this can take a lot of resources/ introduce delays.